# How could i parse the html into dictionary in elegant way

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to parse the html into dictionary

My current code has lots of logic in it.

It smells bad, I use the lxml to help me to parse it.
Any recommend method to parse the kind of html without too much well-formed DOM ?

Thanks so much

## original html

```
<p><strong>Departs:</strong> 5:15:00AM, Sat, Nov 28, 2015 - Taipei</p>
<p><strong>Arrives:</strong> 8:00:00AM, Sat, Nov 28, 2015 - Bangkok - Don Mueang</p>
<p><strong>Flight duration:</strong> 3h 45m</p>
<p><strong>Operated by:</strong> NokScoot</p>
```

## expected result

```
{
    Departs: "5:15:00AM, Sat, Nov 28, 2015",
    Arrives: "5:15:00AM, Sat, Nov 28, 2015",
    Flight duration: "3h 45m"
    ...
}
```

## current code (implementing)

```
doc_root = html.document_fromstring(resp.text)
for ele in doc_root.xpath('//ul[@class="tb_body"]'):
  if has_stops(ele.xpath('.//li[@class="tb_body_flight"]//span[@class="has_cuspopup"]')):
    continue 
  set_trace()
  from_city = ele.xpath('.//li[@class="tb_body_city"]')[0]
  set_trace()
  sub_ele = ele.xpath('.//li[@class="tb_body_flight"]//span[@class="has_cuspopup"]')
  set_trace()
```

Comment: Please post the actual HTML that you are parsing. The HTML you have provided doesn't match your code.

Answer (score 0):

I created example for html you provided. It uses popular [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = '<p><strong>Departs:</strong> 5:15:00AM, Sat, Nov 28, 2015 - Taipei</p>\
        <p><strong>Arrives:</strong> 8:00:00AM, Sat, Nov 28, 2015 - Bangkok - Don Mueang</p>\
        <p><strong>Flight duration:</strong> 3h 45m</p>\
        <p><strong>Operated by:</strong> NokScoot</p>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
res = {p.contents[0].text: p.contents[1].split(' - ')[0].strip() for p in soup.find_all('p')}
print(res)
```

Output:

```
{
    'Departs:': '5:15:00AM, Sat, Nov 28, 2015', 
    'Flight duration:': '3h 45m', 
    'Operated by:': 'NokScoot', 
    'Arrives:': '8:00:00AM, Sat, Nov 28, 2015'
}
```

I think you should avoid of using attributes if you want to make your code compact.